# Editing PhpMyAdmin left side database frame

Tags: phpmyadmin

One of my clients hosting servers recently updated to the new PhpMyAdmin that has the weird nested tree structure of databases and tables on the left hand side and you're no longer able to see all (or many) of the tables of the database without scrolling through several pages in the tiny left hand pane.

I'm rarely one to complain about software updates that change the UI, but this one has got me frustrated because it moves common functionality and hides it behind several other clicks / pages and it's frustrating when trying to work at a decent pace.

Does anyone know whether there's a config option, theme or edit that can be made to revert this style back to the old version, where I just click on the database I'm working with and get to see all the tables that are part of that database and not have the nested tree format? I'd even settle for the nested tree format but with the ability to see more than 15-20 tables on a page.

Comment: With the version 4.4 of phpMyAdmin (soon to be released I think), it will be possible to revert back to old-style navigation panel with a database selector and only current databases' tables being displayed. For switching this behavior, set configuration option $cfg['ShowDatabasesNavigationAsTree'] to 'false'.

Answer (score 2):

There is no config option to revert to pre-4.0 behavior.

However, there is a directive (see https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeDisplayDbFilterMinimum) that permits to display a database name filter box. Entering a database name in the filter box gives you room to see more table names.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution but haven't found one. So I did some investigating. There isn't a config option but if you're OK editing PHP, open the phpmyadmin directory then the file: `/libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php` and on line`553` (in my version at least, 4.0.4) you'll see:

```
if ($prefix_pos !== false) {
```

Change it to:

```
if (false) {
```

This tricks it into thinking there are no prefix matches and will list all the databases without the trees. :)

I hpe that